# gate not working in blade laravel with @can

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, jwt, authorization

I use vue.js and Laravel in my project
Everything is fine except the Laravel blade page, in which @can does not work always return flase

blade.php:

```
@can('show_users')
     <span >"users</span>
@endcan
```

AuthServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(): void
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    foreach (Permission::all() as $permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasPermission($permission);
        });
    }
}
```

in user model:

```
public function hasRole($roles){
    return !! $roles->intersect($this->roles)->all();
}

public function hasPermission($permission)
{
    return $this->permissions->contains('name',$permission->name) || $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
}
```

in config.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

gate working in controller as fine
I use jwt (https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)  for Authentication.Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: Did you try php artisan view:clear?